# invalid user-defined conversion to rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

What is reasoning behind the fact that most versions gcc, except  4.9.0-4.9.4 and 9.1.0, consider this C++11 code ill-formed unless `-pedantic` and `-fpermissive` options are used at same time?
clang compiles it.

```
struct A {
    int a;
    operator int() &&  { return a; }
    operator int&() &  { return a; }
};

void b(int &&) {}

int main()
{
    b(A{});
}
```

Output is similar to:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:11:10: error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'A' to 'int&&' [-fpermissive]
     b(A{});
          ^
prog.cc:4:5: note: candidate is: A::operator int&() & <near match>
     operator int&() &  { return a;
```

Comment: Try `operator int && ()  { return std::move(a); }`. I'd assume `operator int() &&` returns `int`, not `int &&` and gcc correctly determines, that it cannot choose from two near overloads (`int&` and `int`), when trying to match `int&&`.

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say it's related to this https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86521

Comment: @RadosławCybulski in that case choice of operator is determined by function prototype not by type of the expression. Of course that one works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to StoryTeller comment, the problem  is clearly related to intermediate bugs in implementation and they fixes, possible solution may be:

```
#include <utility> //std::move
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int a;
    operator int const& () const  { std::cout <<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<std::endl; return a; }
    operator int&&() &&   { std::cout <<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__<<std::endl;  return std::move(a); }
};

void b(int &&) {}
void b(const int &) {}

int main()
{
    b(A{});
    b(std::move(A{}));
    A a;
    b(a);
}
```

Output:

> ```
> A::operator int&&() &&
> A::operator int&&() &&
> A::operator const int&() const
> ```